# How to prevent contents of div tag not to disappears when webpage shrinks in x axis?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page that has left and right main columns, left column has two main rows, and right column has two internal columns. When web page shrinks in x axis the content of the right column (two internal columns) either disappears or drops below main div that contains the content of the page.

So far I have tried using the overflow and overflow-x variables set to hidden or clip on the right main column div tag but the problem still persists. Please help thank you.

My Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Vancouver Simulator Schedule</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>      
        <div class="logo_container">
            <img class="logo_img"></img>
        </div>
        
        <div class="schedule_body commonGlass_bg">
            
            
            <div class="leftMainColumn">
                <div Class="leftMainColumn_header testWhite_bg">
                </div>
                <div Class="leftMainColumn_body testWhite_bg">
                </div>  
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="rightMainColumn">
                <div class="ffs_column testWhite_bg"></div>
                <div class="ipt_column testWhite_bg"></div>                     
            </div>
        </div>                      
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS file:

```
/* CSS code V2.1*/

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #002855;
    background-image: url("backgroundimg2.jpg");
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    overflow: auto; 
        
}


.header_tab {   
    
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 110px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    float: bottom;

}

.commonGlass_bg {
    
    /*Hex color code below is: 5C677D, rgb value: 92, 103, 125, */
    background: rgba(92, 103, 125, 0.5);
    
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: contrast(3) blur(5px);
    backdrop-filter: contrast(4) blur(5px);
    
}

.logo_container {
    
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    
}

.logo_img {
    
    content:url("logo.svg");
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
}

.schedule_body{
    
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: block;     
        
    height: 84vh;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}

.commonBlueGlass_bg {   
    
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: contrast(3) blur(15px);
    backdrop-filter: contrast(4) blur(15px);    
    
}

.testDark_bg{
    
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    
}

.testWhite_bg{
    
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    
}

/************************************************************************
                Left Main Column (time)
************************************************************************/
.leftMainColumn{    
    
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;   
    /*margin: 5px;*/
    padding: 3px;
    
    /*
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    /*padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;    
    */
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

/***************************************
        Header of Left Main Column
***************************************/
.leftMainColumn_header{
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 24%;
    margin: 1px;
    float: top;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    
    
}

/***************************************
        Body of Left Main Column
***************************************/
.leftMainColumn_body{
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 74%;
    margin: 1px;
    float: top;
    
    margin-top: 4px;
    
}

/************************************************************************
                Right Main Column (Sims. and Session data)
************************************************************************/
.rightMainColumn{
    
    width: 79%;
    float: right;
    /*margin: 5px;*/
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    
    padding: 2px;
    overflow-x: clip;
    flex-shrink: 1; 
    
    /*
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    */
}

.ffs_column{
    width: 60%;
    height: 99%;
    
    margin: 1px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    
    flex-shrink: 1;
    float: left;
    
    
}

.ipt_column{
    
    width: 39%;
    height: 99%;    
    float: right;
    
    
    flex-shrink: 2;
    margin-left: 5px;   
    margin: 1px;
    
}
```

Comment: i dont know how to solve the problem but I dont think you are supposed to use float, or width with flex. if you are using flex the divs should shrink or stack automatically especially if you have flex-wrap on